# Add custom form with shopify e-commerce theme

Tags: shopify

I am new to shopify e-commerce site. i want to add new page with custom form in my theme and that form make to process the search product of my store. finally, all product display in that page according to customer search. how can i achive? is any possible by PHP?

i cannot understand where i locate the new html file and also where and how i get the
product from my shop. can anyone explain the procedure? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to add a new page for search form ( it would be there already in your active theme ) You don't have to add a new page for this purpose.

In your theme editor window under Templates section you can find `search.liquid` file, this is the file, which responsible to render all your searched products.

You can read more details regarding shopify theme development at http://docs.shopify.com/themes/theme-development/templates

Comment: Yes mycholan. there is separate template for search. but can we customize that search template according to our requirements? i mean can we add or delete extra fields and pass different values by that field such that?

Comment: Yes you can change but Only the appearance ( like changing search templates layout displaying product attributes - title, thumbnail, price .. ). but if you wanted to change the way search action performed by shopify, no you are out of luck. may be you can find what you want at https://apps.shopify.com/search/query?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=search

Comment: oh fine. Thanks mycholan.